# Create an isolated dependency scope with "overrides" in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, scope

Some of the classes in my multi-tenant Asp.Net Core application depend on database repositories which in turn depend on a delegate called `GetCurrentTenantKey`.

In the normal request pipeline, the `GetCurrentTenantKey` delegate will be resolved to a `Func` that returns the tenant key found in the current users auth token.

But then I have a few background tasks that also need access to repositories, and in those cases, the tenant key doesn't come from any "current user", rather I'd like to provide it then and there. I thought the best solution would be to manually bind `GetCurrentTenantKey` to a local `Func`, but I don't want to affect the "normal" dependency tree in any way.

This is the class you'll use to create a scope:

```
public class IsolatedServiceScopeFactory : IServiceScopeFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _services;

    public IsolatedServiceScopeFactory(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public IServiceScope CreateScopeWithOverrides(Func<IServiceCollection, IServiceCollection> overrides)
    {
        var detachedCollection = new ImmutableServiceCollection(_services);

        var collectionWithOverrides = overrides(detachedCollection);

        return collectionWithOverrides.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
    }

    public IServiceScope CreateScope() => _services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
}
```

It's intended to be used like this:

```
using (var serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScopeWithOverrides(x => x
    .AddScoped<GetCurrentTenantKey>(y => () => "any string")
    .AddSingleton<SomeOtherOverride>()
))
{
    // This will be resolved using my "overridden" version of GetCurrentTenantKey
    var myRepository = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository<SomeType>>();
}
```

The `ImmutableServiceCollection` class is quite simple:

```
public class ImmutableServiceCollection : IServiceCollection
{
    private ImmutableList<ServiceDescriptor> _services;

    public ImmutableServiceCollection(IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> services)
    {
        _services = services.ToImmutableList();
    }

    public IEnumerator<ServiceDescriptor> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _services.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(ServiceDescriptor item)
    {
        _services = _services.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _services = _services.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(ServiceDescriptor item)
    {
        return _services.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(ServiceDescriptor[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _services.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(ServiceDescriptor item)
    {
        var removed = _services.Contains(item);
        _services = _services.Remove(item);

        return removed;
    }

    public int Count => _services.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; } = true;

    public int IndexOf(ServiceDescriptor item)
    {
        return _services.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, ServiceDescriptor item)
    {
        _services = _services.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _services = _services.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public ServiceDescriptor this[int index]
    {
        get => _services[index];
        set => _services = _services.SetItem(index, value);
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I've maybe went about this the wrong way somehow?

Comment: For anyone coming across this question: I crossposted this question on SO, and got a good suggestion which I marked as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61344944/1087842

Answer (score 1):

**Use a mutable, scoped wrapper**
I just finished ripping this out of a codebase and thought I'd mention a couple things...

1. I was migrating some API projects from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 and updating libraries too
2. [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/) & [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) didn't like the approach mentioned above
3. It appears the `collectionWithOverrides.BuildServiceProvider()` command
   prevents shared singletons
4. I was getting `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

To pass 'out of band' information I used a mutable "wrapper" object that was defined in DI 'Scope'...

```
public static async Task SomeActionThatNeedsAnAccountId(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, string accountId)
{
    using (var serviceScope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var serviceProvider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
        
        var wrapper = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyMutableWrapper>();
        wrapper.AccountId = accountId;
        
        var myService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyService>();
        await myService.PerformActionAsync();
    }
}
```

`MyService` depends on an `IAccountIdProvider` and `MyMutableWrapper : IAccountIdProvider`.
In Startup.cs: `services.AddScoped<IAccountIdProvider, MyMutableWrapper>()`

Comment: Hi Peter. I had forgotten I posted this question here as well. Anyway, I did receive an answer on SO which I've been using ever since, so I don't really have a reason to try other options. Have a look if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61344944/1087842

Comment: Wow, that's almost identical to my answer. Hopefully others will find this answer useful as they wonder where `IsolatedServiceScopeFactory` originated (as they maintain an inherited codebase).